# How to display a List of Chips?

Tags: flutter, list, dart

I have a `main screen` with a button that `Push`es the user to a new screen to enter in data.

The user can then input data and the data is mapped to a `list` that displays `chips` as below:

```
_chipList
                    .map(
                      (chip) => Chip(
                        label: Text(chip.name + ' ' + chip.weight.toString()),
                        onDeleted: () {
                          deleteChips(chip.id);
                        },
                      ),
                    )
                    .toList(),
```

I then pop the screen when the user presses back, sending the `context` and `_chipList` back to the main screen using `Navigator.pop(context, _chipList`.

I receive the list and can print it by `overriding` the `toString()` method in the `ChipModel` class like so:

`@override toString() => 'ChipModel: $name $weight';`

How do I iterate through the list to display them as chips like how they were mapped before?

Example of what I want to achieve:

[image]

My `ChipModel` is as follows:

```
class ChipModel {
  final String id;
  final String name;
  final double weight;

  ChipModel({
    required this.id,
    required this.name,
    required this.weight,
  });
  @override toString() => 'ChipModel: $name $weight';
}
```

*Edit:

My main screen is as follows but List of chips does not show:

```
_chipList.isEmpty ? InkWell(
                            onTap: () {
                                  _navigateToIngredientScreen(context);
                                },
                                child: Container(
                                  width: width - 16,
                                  height: 50,
                                  child: Center(
                                    child: Text(
                                      'Add Ingredients',
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        color: secondaryColor,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              )
                            : Column(
                                children: [
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                    child: Wrap(
                                      spacing: 10,
                                      children: _chipList
                                          .map(
                                            (chip) => Chip(
                                              label: Text(chip.name +
                                                  ' ' +
                                                  chip.weight.toString()),
                                              onDeleted: () {
                                                deleteChips(chip.id);
                                              },
                                            ),
                                          )
                                          .toList(),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Expanded(
                                      child: Align(
                                    alignment: FractionalOffset.bottomCenter,
                                    child: Row(children: []),
                                  ))
                                ],
                              ),
```

And the method to get the `_chipList`:

```
  Future<void> _navigateToIngredientScreen(BuildContext context) async {
    _chipList = await Navigator.of(context).push(
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => AddIngredientsScreen(),
      ),
    );
    if(!mounted) return;

    print(_chipList.toString());
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Wrap](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Wrap-class.html) widget,

```dart
Wrap(
  children: _chipList
     .map(....).toList(),
```

Comment: I have tried to use the same method above but the chips do not get populated by the received List from the `new screen`. Updated question to show usage.

Comment: make sure add `await` on `push`. and call setState after it. Also it will be easy if you include full sample widget

Comment: I did use `await` on the `Navigator.of(context).push` but I didn't call the setState. Where would I call `setState`?

Comment: after `print(_chi...`